# Is a Bayesian framework more in keeping with neurobiologic processes?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, mathematical-statistics

Human thinking appears based on intercommunicating neurons and plastic synapses.

In keeping with these neurobiologic premises and the evident assumption that every human thought, hypothesis and theory must first exist as a specific connection between neurons, is a Bayesian statistical framework more neurobiologically coherent and plausible than a frequentist one?

Comment: Sounds very interesting!!! Can you give more insight with an outline of what are the random variables you are trying to model ?

Comment: This is speculative and assumes very simplistic concept of human brain...

Comment: @Tim I accept your criticism. However, beyond neurons and synapses, how can we envision the neurobiology of a statistical hypothesis?

Comment: It has nothing go do with neurobiology... Moreover, I can't see any reason at all why should we make science / logic / mathematics similar to how our brain works -- people and animals have all kinds of cognitive biases, react emotionally rather then based on logical reasoning etc. so brain is very *imperfect* machinery. Would you like mathematics to copy the cognitive biases we have? If yes, then basically we do not need statistics as we can reason on our own without it's "lies".

Answer (score 1):

This question probably is too broad and philosophical to be answered here, but I would just like to refer you to E.T. Jaynes, who also argued that any reasonable human thoughts should follow Bayesian principles. He argues it on the basis of logic, though, rather than biology, hence his paper [How does the brain do plausible reasoning?](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/brain.pdf) was initially rejected. The most interesting part of it is the correspondence which can be seen in full in the end of [this PDF](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/how.does.the.brain.orig.pdf) and is a window into science communication 60 years ago, between the reviewer:

> [Jaynes] makes some statement that reasoning about natural science and mathematics is the kind of reasoning that is least perturbed by a given amount of imperfection of the human brain. It seems to me that the behavior of mildly intoxicated scientists at a party provides a counter example. The ability to react successfully to many situations in daily life is retained long after the individual has lost the ability to do rapid correct arithmetic.

, the editor:

> You are not really discussing functioning of the brain but rather showing a possible axiomatic derivation of probability theory. It is almost as if Euclid had called his Elements "How does the Brain do Geometric Reasoning!"

and Jaynes:

> I will remove the features which the referees did not like (i.e. remove the words "human brain"), and shorten the paper by about a factor of two, before re-submitting it.